# Origin of Nikkud signs names in Rabbinical literature

Tags: vowels-nekudot

The [WIKI page for Nikkud](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93) says it appeared long after the Gemmorah.

Is Nikkud mentioned in Rabbinical literature before Rishonim - the names of the signs and the ways of using them? If not, what are the first books that mention it?

Comment: Maybe worth clarifying which system of Nikkud you’re asking about. Is it specifically the Tiberian one?

Comment: The names of Tiberian marks are present in Tiberian masoretic manuscripts. That's where they come from (almost by definition). Does that count?

Comment: See Rambam Sefer Torah 8:4

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Have you looked at Keter Yerushalayim? Based, as much as possible, on the same Tanach (Keter Aram Tzovah).

Comment: It is at least strange that here for example they don't use names to make the thing clearer: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nedarim.37b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @kazi also gemara pesachim about yeiachel, avoda zarah about dodayikh, bava batra about zakhar, all could have used names of vowels to be clearer

Comment: The earliest Sefer which Sefaria has which refers to the Nekudos AFAICT is https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Explanation_of_the_Seven_Vowels,_Introduction.1. The compilation is dated at 1915; does anyone know if this particular Midrash dates further back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kazi, I bring an earlier (and more exact source אישא Aron Dotan quotes p.90) for Nikkud from the book [מסורת המסורת לר' אליהו המדקדק](http://hebrewbooks.org/20911) (circa 1500):

> הקדמה השלישית: "הנה דעת רוב האנשים
>   שעזרא הסופר וסיעתו שהם אנשי כנסת הגדולה
>   עשו המסורת והניקוד והטעמים על כל המקרא,
>   ומביאים ראי' ממה שדרשו רז"ל בנדרים (לז,ב). . .
>   .
>   והא לך דעתי בענין הזה,
>   **אחשוב שהנקודות והטעמים לא היו קודם עזרא
>
>   ולא בזמן עזרא ולא אחר עזרא
>
>   עד אחר חתימת התלמוד**",
>   ע"ש בארוכה.

Also in the name of Nitronay Gaon ([Machzor Vitri 425](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49459&st=&pgnum=68))<sup>exact source needed</sup>:

> "וששאלתם אם אסור לנקד ספר התורה (תשובה:) ספר תורה שניתן למשה מסיני לא שמענו בו ניקוד, ולא ניתן ניקוד מסיני, כי החכמים ציינוהו לסימן, ואסור לנו להוסיף מדעתנו, פן נעבור על בל תוסיף עכ"ל.

See also [discussion on Nikkud on WIKI](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%94%3A%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93#%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D).

Comment: Check the last few rows of this: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49459&st=&pgnum=68

Comment: @Kazibácsi WOW how do you do that?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I didn't understand it so well, he contradicts himself saying 1. Nikkud was from the Rabbis, that's why it's different everywhere 2. It's from Sinai (הקרייה במסורת מסיני) What do you understand?

Comment: First of all, saying Machzor Vitry is contradictory, is a bit strong statement, at least you don't understand his point. Second, you may accept whichever answer you want, including your one, but there is a very strong proof that there was an oral tradition from Sinai (and this is what MV is talking about) that was not written down until scribes did so (MV tells you why). These scribes can't be earlier than the Talmud, so discussing Ezra is pointless. Last, on this site you should translate or summarise Hebrew sources in your answers.

Answer (score 4):

There's a really good paper by the great scholar *Aron Dotan,* called [The Relative Chronology of Hebrew Vocalization and Accentuation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3622434) (can be read for free after registration), where he discusses the issue and concludes (p. 89):

> No mention is made of the signs in either of the Talmuds or in any of the
> early Midrashim, although one would expect to find the subject
> there in conjunction with the many references to Torah-reading
> or to masoretic matters and the like. The signs are not
> mentioned simply because they were not in existence around
> 500 CE, when the Babylonian Talmud was completed.

Among other evidence he says that Shir haShirim Rabba lacks to comment the following verse from the Song of Songs ([1:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3001.htm#11)):

> תּוֹרֵ֤י זָהָב֙ נַֽעֲשֶׂה־לָּ֔ךְ עִ֖ם **נְקֻדּ֥וֹת הַכָּֽסֶף**׃
>
> We will make thee circlets of gold with studs of silver.

Here the *points of silver* (נְקֻדּ֥וֹת הַכָּֽסֶף) *"literally cries out for an allusion to niqqud."*

Therefore the first known references to the names of the Tiberian vowels are from [Ben Asher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_ben_Moses_ben_Asher) (10th century) himself in the [Dikdukei Teamim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38509&st=&pgnum=53) (p. 12):

> שם הנקודות: קָמְצָה, פָּתְחָה, צְרֵי, סֶגוֹל, חֹלֶם, שֻׁרֶק, חִרֵק.‏

Comment: Dikdukei Taamim isn't the earliest masoretic work in existence, is it? Surely the names are present in notes on manuscripts, even partial ones, that precede it.

Comment: I'll just note the Zohar uses the names that were in common use in the mideival period. If you assume those sections date from earlier then indeed there is early evidence of an early top-secret naming system of Nikkud that wasn't widely known. (Not clear why there'd be such a system that only had secret names, or why there'd be a system of written Nikkud that nearly no one could refer to, but it is strictly speaking possible.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I suppose it's a nasty thing to come up with the Zohar, because it's extremely hard to date its different parts. A better argument is the question of earlier works. Here the problem is that earlier systems do not distinguish all the vowels that we know. In the earlier Eretz Yisrael system _patach/kamatz_ is the same, in Babylonia they had the same sign for _patach_ and _segol._ One is sure that there was an oral tradition with vowels that comes from Sinai, and these vowel signs were created by the scribes according to Nedarim 37b.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is just striking that in the hundreds of _al tikrei_ examples in the Talmud they don't say the difference with the names of the vowels. So there's a strong evidence that the names didn't exist in the era of the Talmud. The manuscripts start to emerge from the 7th century CE, where you can figure out a few things from the Babylonian tradition, as they were writing Hebrew letters above the text. But I am not aware of a properly dated masoretic document that lists the names of the vowels (if you do, please edit in).

Comment: This is fascinating! I just posted another question on this topic and another one on your quote in Nedorim.

Comment: Are the vowels in the list of vowel names original? I'm skeptical

Comment: Text is always better than pictures of text for this site

Comment: @DoubleAA Unfortunately I don't know what manuscript did they use

Comment: Steiner has an article about the history of pronunciation of the vowel names, you might enjoy

Comment: @DoubleAA This one? https://www.jstor.org/stable/43076973

Comment: Yes I think so.